# Does "fail the channel" mean unilateral close in BOLTS?

Tags: lightning-network, lightning-rfc

The BOLTs frequently mentioned "fail the channel" when something unexpected is received or happens. For instance, when receiving an [update_fulfill_htlc](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lightning-rfc/blob/master/02-peer-protocol.md#removing-an-htlc-update_fulfill_htlc-update_fail_htlc-and-update_fail_malformed_htlc) message, you should fail the channel if the received channel ID isn't known.

At this point, you would have money stuck in a channel, so does this mean you should try to close unilaterally, cooperatively, either? Is "fail the channel" defined in the bolts somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

The meaning is defined in [BOLT #5 Failing a Channel](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lightning-rfc/blob/master/05-onchain.md#failing-a-channel).